# How can you add an image to a listbox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am wanting to add an image to the top or background of a listbox.  I would like it to be visible on the screen, but more importantly is that it prints.  Can someone help me with the code for this.  I tried to see if you could add it through properties and don't see that option.  I need the listbox not listview.  Also I was wondering if it could be added as a string and the file referenced at the top of the listbox (when you right click the little arrow and click edit options?  Can someone please help.  I am working on a project and still very new at this.

Comment: `WPF` would be the way to go. Printing will have nothing to do with the control itself. You will have to do that yourself with a `PrintDocument` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom ListBox class and add the ability to draw a custom background by overriding the OnPaint event, like on:

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?416784-2005-ListBox-Background-Image